# Where to find Azure database sync

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We've been getting a bunch of errors in the Windows error log for the sql sync tool, and I was going to log into Azure to see if I can figure out what is causing the error.

It's been a while since I've needed to log in to Azure, and the dashboard has been updated.

**I do not know where to find the option to trigger a sync anymore.**

I also don't find the option to see the logs (which I'm pretty sure I looked at the last time we had data sync issues), and we have an option to upgrade to v12 that I need to see if we want to do.
Also, apparently they retired the web tier and I have to look at switching tiers, or maybe see if I can just stay with the tier we're on.

It's all kind of confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure Data Sync is not supported on the new portal. The team is working on it. 
Please use the old portal https://manage.windowsazure.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com